# How to use global variables in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, global

I want to use specific data as a global variable.

I thought about inserted it in the `DataBase`, but I thought it would be used too often, so I decided to leave it as a global variable.

However, I can't find it well even when I search for how to register.

The value is set at the start of the nestjs and does not change.
There will be 3 global variables.

How can I register?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve it:

1. You can create a normal class and add the values of the constant as properties.
2. If the data is more likely to change (configuration, etc..) I would recommend
   creating a config module or using the NestJS out-of-the-box config module to
   make it simpler.

Both of the options are good in my opinion, if we are talking about a small number of variables I would not recommend storing constants in a database.

Comment: thank you I'm going to try method #1!